# Use static_cast in a class hierarchy to enable visitor pattern

Tags: c++

Imagine following scenario. I derive from a library class to enable the visitor pattern:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct MyClassA;
struct MyClassB;

struct MyVisitor{
    virtual void visit(MyClassA* c) { std::cout << "My Class A" << std::endl; }
    virtual void visit(MyClassB* c) { std::cout << "My Class B" << std::endl; }
};

struct LibClass {};

struct MyClass : public LibClass {
    virtual void Accept(MyVisitor& visitor) = 0;
};

struct MyClassA : public MyClass {
    virtual void Accept(MyVisitor& visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
};
struct MyClassB : public MyClass {
    virtual void Accept(MyVisitor& visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
};

// vector signature can't be changed
void foo(std::vector<LibClass*>& v) {
    MyVisitor visitor;

    for(auto libC : v) {
        auto myC = static_cast<MyClass*>(libC); // questionable line
        //auto myC = dynamic_cast<MyClass*>(libC); // don't want to use dynamic cast
        myC->Accept(visitor);
    }
}

int main() {
    // vector signature can't be changed
    std::vector<LibClass*> v;    
    v.push_back(new MyClassA()); 
    v.push_back(new MyClassB()); 
    foo(v);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is as expected:

```
My Class A
My Class B
```

This is a question regarding design. In my eyes, it is bad style to use `dynamic_cast` and should be avoided. As the vector can get quite large, I also want to avoid calls on the iteration to `dynamic_cast`.
I can be sure, that every pointer in the vector is derived from `MyClass`.
I want to use the visitor pattern to implement features depending on the derived class, so I will implement derived classes of `MyVisitor`, too. `MyVisitor` later could be provide a virtual interface for all possible childrens. The concrete Visitors than can override only that methods, on which children they want to interact with.

So my questions are:

- Is there any danger using the `static_cast` in that way?
- Would you consider this a good design under the circumstance, that I want to insert the possibilty to use the visitor pattern?

Comment: “In my eyes, it is bad style to use `dynamic_cast` and should be avoided.” — you haven’t explained *why* you think that (there are reasons, but some of them apply equally to `static_cast`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph in my code it would be bad style, because I would misuse dynamic_cast as a switch. (Because if I use a dynamic_cast, I don't need the visitor at all) I want to use the visitor to differentiate between types than RTTI (or dynamic_cast)

Answer (score 2):

`dynamic_cast` is safer (assuming checking for `nullptr`) as compiler might check at runtime that the class is really what you want. (No compile-time hierarchy check, due to possible multiple inheritance). `foo` can be used safely (Even by `LibClass` which are not `MyClass`).

With `static_cast`, you do a **promise** to the compiler. Breaking it would lead to UB.
The only check done at compile time is that derived class (`MyClass`) is actually in the hierarchy of the base class (`LibClass`).
`foo` signature is now misleading, as you expect only `MyClass` instead of any `LibClass`.
But as long as you don't break that promise, code is ok.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX: it would be mostly equivalent to a virtual call, that you would also do for visitor...

Comment: dynamic_cast has slight runtime overhead, which is fine in most cases anyways. dynamic_cast is safer as it returns nullptr if the object is not a type of what you expected.